# One columned datatable to List<string>

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `datatable` which contains only one column and all items are strings. How can I convert this to a `List<string>` using LINQ for example?

I Tried:

```
DataRow[] rows = dtusers.Select();
var qq = from RowCollection in rows
         select new { UserCode = LibStatic.ToStr(RowCollection["UserCode"]) };

List<string> users = new List<string>();
users = qq.Cast<string>().ToList();
```

There is the easyway which always works:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dtusers.Rows)
{
    users.Add(dr[0].ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You can use [LINQ query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552415.aspx) to do that.

```
List<string> list = dtusers.AsEnumerable()
                           .Select(r=> r.Field<string>("UserCode"))
                           .ToList();
```

Comment: thanks, For anyone wanna avoid column name use .Select(r => r.Field<string>(0))

Comment: i got an error EnumerableRowCollection does not contain definition for List<string>.. in this case import System.LinQ package to your class

Answer (score 5):

You can try this code,

```
List<string> list = dt.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().Select(dr => (string)dr["ColumnName"]).ToList();
```