# Using DataTable.Compute filter on null entries

Tags: c#, datatable, null, standard-deviation, dbnull

Suppose that there is a `DataTable dt` of type `double` with the columns `"x","y","z"` in C#.

While values are filled into `dt`, it certainly occurs that only two dimensions are assigned a being assigned which intentionally leaves the third vacant with `DBNull.Value`.

When computing the average for a dimension with a filter according to [Transact-SQL syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/is-null-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15) things work properly:

```
X = (double)dt.Compute("Avg([x])", "x IS NOT NULL");
```

However, the following results in `System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'`

```
sx = (double)dt.Compute("StDev([x])", "x IS NOT NULL");
```

This would be highly convenient compared to [a seperate method to calculate the standard deviation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895929/how-do-i-determine-the-standard-deviation-stddev-of-a-set-of-values) .
And even at this point there is trouble when [converting a column with null values into a List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15129770/one-columned-datatable-to-liststring):

```
List<double> xValues = dt.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().Select(dr => dt.Field<double>("x")).ToList();
```

`System.InvalidCastException: 'Cannot cast DBNull.Value to type 'System.Double'. Please use a nullable type.'`

Any suggestions on handling this situation be it with [null-conditionals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) or suggestions on the filter are highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using a nullable type as the error suggests? `dt.Field<double?>` If you don't want the `null` values, you could add a `.Where(field => field != null)` before the `.ToList()`

Comment: Using `dt.Field<double?>` as a workaround to generate a list certainly works - ty. Still looking for a solution/ explanation regarding the `dt.Compute()`

Comment: They are the same, I made an edit. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Not sure why that would happen, but according to the Remarks section of the [STDEV (Transact-SQL) documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stdev-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), *"Null values are ignored"*. Have you tried just using an empty string for the filter?

Comment: `sx = (double)dt.Compute("StDev([x])", "");` leads to `System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'`